# Clarify the concept of Multiple inheritance: Can a diamond structure issue occur?

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

**Suppose you have two interfaces I1 and I2 both the interfaces have the same method**

```
1)public int add(int a) throws exception e1    //(Interface 1)

2)public int add(int a) throws exception e2    //(Interface 2)
```

**now a class implements both I1 and I2.**

```
@override
public int add(int a) exception e1
{
//adding operation
}
```

Note: *I understand that if you implement multiple interfaces which have same method then only one implementation will be there in the implementing class.*

1. Does the compiler infer whether this method is from I1 or I2 based on the throws clause? Is method signature clarification required? (I know that signature include name and parameters passed.)
2. If we have implemented both the interfaces and then we are throwing only e1 will the compiler allow this since the implementing class doesn't really implement both interfaces? will it cause **diamond structure** problem?
3. Do we need to implement the same method with throws clause e1 and 2nd time e2? When I tried this the compiler told me I had duplicate methods.
4. If we implement the I1 first then it says that it is I1's method and if we write the I2 first then it says its I2's method.  Explain why this is so.

Comment: The implementing function must implement all interfaces. This may require it to not throw *any* exceptions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB:Can you please explain a little about "This may require it to not throw any exceptions"I am saying the class implemented only one method with no exception? so what should it say? I1 's method + I2 's method?Or if it write throws e1 will the compiler know this method is from I1?  **Thanks

Comment: What are you talking about? What does 'it should say' mean? Who should say? Say when?

Comment: "it should say" i was talking about "my eclipse"

Comment: A more proper question would be 'is this correct?' instead of asking obscurely about highly abbreviated versions of what an IDE should display that are so abbreviated as to be themselves incomprehensible. It is not the function of StackOverflow to vote on IDE error messages. If you're asking whether the IDE is wrong in what it *is* saying, it is zillions of times more likely that your code is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interface defines a contract. If an interface defines a method

```
void foo() throws SomeException;
```

then it says: all implementing classes must have a method foo, returning void, not taking any argument, and which is allowed to throw SomeException **but no other type of checkd exception**.

The implementing method may of course choose to not throw any exception at all, since it would not violate the contract of the interface method. `throws` means: this method might throw this exception in some circumstances.

So, a method declared as

```
public void foo();
```

in an implementing class is valid for the interface defined above.

So, in your example,

```
public int add(int a) throws Exception1
```

is a valid method declaration to override

```
int add(int a) throws Exception1
```

but is **not** valid for

```
int add(int a) throws Exception2
```

(unless of course Exception1 is a subclass of Exception2).

The only way, if there is no inheritance between Excption1 and Exception2, to implement both interfaces is to have a method that doesn't throw any exception. That is the only possibility to fullfill the two contracts.

Comment: Thanks for your interest :) but if I write int add(int a)throws Exception2 and while implementing the interface className implements I2,I1 at this point it says I1's method for the implementation? how is it happening? because of the order? I2 implemented first? does it really make any sense?

Comment: The method in the implementing class MUST implement the method `add()` from I1 **and** the method `add()` from I2. It implements both at once. There is no ordering involved. As soon as your class says that it implements I1 and I2, either it actually implements both, or you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to overriding, only the parameter types of methods are considered [(8.4.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2); return types and throw types are  checked later in a separate step [(8.4.8.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

It is possible for a class to inherit multiple methods with override-equivalent
signatures. [(8.4.8.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4) There is no problem there. In your case, two methods are inherited, then both are overridden by one method.

My IDE IntelliJ correctly reports that the method overrides two methods in two super interfaces.

In Java 7 and earlier, there is no diamond problem. However since Java 8, interface methods can have implementations! Therefore the diamond problem can occur when a class inherits two methods from two interfaces. Javac may reject the code if such ambiguity exists. (There are ways to disambiguate).

Comment: I think the diamond problem would only occur if a derived interface were allowed to declare an implementation for one of its parent members, and I wouldn't think that would be allowed.  Is it, or can a diamond problem happen some other way?

Comment: an interface can have a `default` method that overrides a parent's method.

Comment: Interesting.  I would have thought the main usage case for adding default methods in an interface would be to allow new methods to be added to an interface without breaking existing implementations, and that usage case would only require adding methods to the parent.  I can see a problem with this feature, though, and it goes beyond the diamond: since (unlike VB.NET) Java does not require that methods which implement interface members be tagged in any way, any interface which adds a new member risks a collision with method names used by any class which implements it.

Comment: What would happen if interface I1 adds a method, interface I2 inherits I1 and adds a final implementation for it, and I2 is implemented by a class which has a private method of that same name used for something else entirely.  Could Java bind the interface to I2's implementation, or would the existence of the class's private method break things?

Comment: that is not a new problem - any time you add a new method to a supertype, it may break existing subtypes. it is quite risky to add default methods to an existing public interface.

Comment: The *historical* expectation has been that adding members to an interface would break implementations, but the purpose of the default-members feature is to avoid that.  Further, it would seem unfortunate if the presence of even private members in a class would create naming conflicts, since at least by my understanding part of the reason for using private members was to avoid any risk that their names would collide with something else.  A compiler warning in case of naming conflict would seem desirable, but a run-time load failure would seem much less so.